# Asynchronous web socket application server with two event loops

Tags: asynchronous, websocket, ipc, message-queue, distributed-computing

I'm trying to make a distributed RPC-type web application that uses websockets for its main interface. I want to use a queuing system (like RabbitMQ) in order to distribute the expensive jobs that are requested through the websocket connections.

Basically, the flow would go like this:

1. A client sends a job via websocket connection to the server
2. The server would send this message to a RabbitMQ exchange to be processed by a worker
3. The worker would execute the job and add the result of the job to a response queue
4. The server would check the response queue and send the result of the job back to the client via websocket connection.

As far as I can tell, on the server I need two event loops that share memory. The websocket server needs to be listening for incoming jobs, and a RabbitMQ consumer needs to be listening for job results to send back to the clients.

What's the appropriate technologies for me to use here? I've considered the following:

- multithreading the application and starting one event loop on each thread
- using two processes with shm (shared memory)
- using two processes that communicate via socket (either a unix socket or maybe even set up the workers as special websocket clients)
- hooking into the websocket server's event loop to check the result queue

I'm new to both websockets and distributed computing, so I really have no idea which of these (or maybe something I didn't think of) would work best for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I can tell, on the server I need two event loops that share memory. The websocket server needs to be listening for incoming jobs, and a RabbitMQ consumer needs to be listening for job results to send back to the clients.

Since you can have multiple clients sending jobs concurrently, you will need a multithreaded server. Unless your application would process client per client. Now there are multiple approaches to implement a multithreaded server, each with their own advantages/disadvantages. Take a look at multithreading through :

1. A thread per request (**+** : throughput potentially maximized, **-** : threads are expensive to create, must manage concurrency)
2. A thread per client (**+** : less thread management overhead, **-** : doesn't scale to many many connections, still manage concurrency)
3. A thread pool (**+** : Avoids overhead of thread creation, scalable up to N concurrent connections (N = size of thread pool), **-** : Manage concurrency between N threads)

It's up to you to choose one of the above approaches *(I would opt for a thread per client as it is relatively easy to implement and the chance that you'll have tens of thousands of clients is relatively small)*.

Notice that this is a multithreaded approach and **not an event-driven approach** ! But since you are not limited to one thread (in which case it should be event driven in order to be able to process multiple clients *"concurrently"*) I wouldn't go for that option as it is more difficult to implement. (Programmers sometimes speak about a "callback hell" in an event-driven approach).

This is how I would implement it *(one thread per client, Java)* :

> Basically, the flow would go like this:
>
> 1. A client sends a job via websocket connection to the server

Server part :

```
public class Server {
    private static ServerSocket server_skt;
    private static ... channel; // channel to communicate with the rabbitMQ distributed priority queue.

    // Constructor
    Server(int port) {
        server_skt = new ServerSocket(port);
        
        /*
         * Set up connection with the distributed queue
         * channel = ...;
         */
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        Server server = new Server(5555); // Make server instance

        while(true) {
            // Always waiting for new clients to connect
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for a client to connect...");
                // Spawn new thread for communication with client (hence one thread per client approach)
                new CommunicationThread(server_skt.accept(), server.channel).start(); // Will listen for new jobs and send them
            } catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception occured :" + e.getStackTrace());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> 2. The server would send this message to a RabbitMQ exchange to be processed by a worker
> 3. ...
> 4. The server would check the response queue and send the result of the job back to the client via websocket connection.

```
public class CommunicationThread extends Thread {
    private Socket client_socket;
    private InputStream client_in;
    private OutputStream client_out;
    private ... channel; // Channel to communicate with rabbitMQ
    private ... resultQueue;

    public CommunicationThread(Socket socket, ... channel) { // replace ... by type of the rabbitMQ channel
        try {
            this.client_socket = socket;
            this.client_in = client_socket.getInputStream();
            this.client_out = client_socket.getOutputStream(); 
            this.channel = channel;
            this.resultQueue = ...;

            System.out.println("Client connected : " + client_socket.getInetAddress().toString());
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not initialize communication properly. -- CommunicationThread.\n");
        }
    }
    
    public yourJobType readJob() {
        // Read input from client (e.g. read a String from "client_in")
        // Make a job from it (e.g. map String to a job)
        // return the job
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(active) {
            
            /*
             * Always listen for incoming jobs (sent by client) and for results (to be sent back to client)
             */
            
            // Read client input (only if available, else it would be blocking!)
            if(client_in.available() > 0) {
                yourJobType job = readJob();
                channel.basicPublish(...); // Send job to rabbitMQ
            }
            
            /* Check result queue (THIS is why reading client input MUST be NON-BLOCKING! Else while loop could be blocked on reading input
             * and the result queue won't be checked until next job arrives)
             */
            
            ResultType next_result = resultQueue.poll(); // Could be "null" if the queue is empty
            if(next_result != null) {
                // There is a result
                client_out.write(next_result.toByteArray());
                client_out.flush();
            }
        }
        
        client_in.close();
        client_out.close();
    }
}
```

**Note** that when reading from the result queue it is important that you **only read results of jobs sent by that client**.

If you have one result queue containing the results of jobs (of all clients) and you retrieve a result like in the code above, then that result could be the result of a job of another client, hence sending the result back the the wrong client.

To fix this you could `poll()` the result queue with a filter and a wildcard (*) or have a result queue for each client, hence knowing that a result retrieved from our queue wil be sent to the corresponding client.

(*) : You could assign an ID to every client. When receiving a job from a client, pair the job with the client ID (e.g. in a tuple *< clientID, job >*) and put it in the queue. And do the same for the results (pair the result with the client ID and put it in the result queue). Then in the `run()` method of `CommunicationThread` you would have to poll the result queue only for results of the form *< clientID, ? >*.

**Important** : You'll also have to assign an ID for every job! Because sending job A and then job B doesn't guarantee that result of job A will come before the result of job B. (Job B could be less time consuming then job A and thus the result could be sent back to the client before job A's result).

(PS : It's up to you to see how to implement the workers (executed by server with one thread for each worker? Or executed by other processes?))

---

The above answer is a possible, multithreaded solution. I only discussed the server part, the client part should send jobs and wait for results (how to implement this depends on your goals, do clients first send **all** jobs and then receive the results of each job or can this be mixed ?).

There are other ways it could be implemented, but for a beginner in distributed computing I think this is the easiest solution (using thread pools, ... would make it trickier).

Comment: Thank you! this is very helpful (over a year later ;) )